# Need help sending Email from form HTML

Tags: html, forms, email, asp-classic, smtp

I have a form that reads

```
<form action="Send.asp" method="POST" name="Order" id="Order">
```

in my send a quote page. The submit button reads as follows:

```
<input name="B1" type="submit" class="style80" value="Submit">
```

Now when I click on the button, it only redirects to the home page. I would like it to go to the .asp file called Send.asp

That .asp file has the sending methods: connect to SMTP server and compile an email form the input boxes on the request page.

Why is my email not sending? What am I missing from the form tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `input type=submit` seems correct. Is the `Send.Asp` page in the same directory than the html file ?. Maybe you have to use other relative route.

Are you debugging Send.asp file to check if it is being called?.

That could be a start.

Try changing aswell the Send.Asp with full url to discard that the url is not valid.

```
form action="http://yoururl/yourproject/Send.asp" method="POST" name="Order" id="Order">
```

Comment: Thanks. The file was in the same folder, just added a / to make sure. The email is now being made, I just have to sort out internal problems with the SMTP server. This one I'm using is old